# why built in function next(iter_obj) when we have method iter_obj.next()

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming, iterator

I'm new to python ,and just trying to figure out why two ways? any specific reason? which one is better?

I've tried searching but not able to find it.

Comment: `next(...)` works in python2 and python3

Comment: And `.next()` doesn't work in Python 3.

Comment: I'm sorry . I didn't get your comment. I don't think that explains my question. leave python3. asking about 2.7! why built in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is that the justification is similar for `next(x)` as it is for `len(x)`. Fredrik Lund summarises Guido's response on that topic in [this article](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm).